# Verilog Down Counter Logic Implementation

Tags: fpga, verilog

I'm trying to write logic for storing trigger data. For example, I'm using a 3-bit counter as an address generator to store data samples. When I have a trigger event, I want to store the 4 data samples just before the trigger event occurred and the 4 after wards. So I use a 2-bit down counter when the trigger occurs and stops the counter when it counts down to 0 thus giving me 4 data samples from before the trigger and 4 data samples after the trigger.
I'm having trouble implementing this though and get only 3 addresses once I start the down counter and it counts down to 0

```
//=== 8-bit wide loadable up-counter =============================
`timescale 1 ns / 1 ps

module fw_up_counter_3 (tc, count, d, ld, en, clk, rst);

output          tc;
output  [2:0]   count;
input   [2:0]   d;
input           ld, en, clk, rst;
reg     [2:0]   l_count;
wire            tc;

assign  tc      = &count[2:0];
assign  count   = l_count ;

always @(posedge clk)
 begin
        if(rst)
                l_count <=      3'b0;
        else if(ld)
                l_count <=      d;
        else if (en & ~ld)
                l_count <=      l_count + 1;
        else
                l_count <=      l_count;
 end
endmodule

//====2-bit wide loadable down-counter=====================
module fw_dn_counter_1(tc, count, en, ld, clk, rst);
  output tc;
  output [1:0] count;
  input en, clk, rst, ld;
  reg [1:0] l_count;
  reg [1:0] d = 2'b11;
  wire tc;

  assign tc = ~|count[1:0];
  assign count = l_count;

  always@(posedge clk)
  begin
    if (rst)
      l_count <= 2'b11;
    else if (ld)
      l_count <= d;
    else if(en & ~ld & ~tc)
      l_count <= l_count - 1;
    else if (l_count == 2'b00)
      l_count <= 2'b00;
    else
      l_count <= l_count;
    end
  endmodule


module trig_test(clk, tc1, tc2, en1, en2, count1, count2, rst, ld, trig, trig_loc);
  input clk, rst, en1, en2, ld;
  output [2:0] count1;
  output [1:0] count2;
  output tc1, tc2;
  input trig;
  output reg [2:0]trig_loc;

  fw_up_counter_3 counter1(.tc(tc1), .count(count1), .d(3'b000), .ld(ld), .en(~tc2), .clk(clk), .rst(rst));

  fw_dn_counter_1 counter2(.tc(tc2), .count(count2), .en(trig) , .ld(ld), .clk(clk), .rst(rst));

  always@(posedge trig)
  begin
      trig_loc <= count1;
  end

endmodule
```

[image]
Anyone have any ideas on where I'm going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`counter2` is reset to state 11. When the `trig` rising edge occurs, it starts counting down.

Your code shows no way to ensure that the `trig` edge is syncronized with your `clk` signal. In your simulation, `trig` goes high very shortly before a `clk` rising edge. So on that edge, `counter2` starts counting down --- going to the 10 state. But in between the `trig` edge and the `clk` edge, you did have a brief period where `counter2` was in the 11 state. So you did in fact have `counter2` in 4 different states after the trigger edge.

If you want to be sure to keep the counter in the 11 state for at least one full `clk` cycle after the trigger, you could  either syncronize `trig` to `clk`, or delay the input to the counter `en` input for one cycle after the trigger is seen (essentially the same thing, but making a new syncronized signal).